# What is the principle behind Dispatch?

Tags: replacement

I want to know what `Dispatch` actually does to rule the list. Why is it so fast?

The documentation says

> Dispatch generates a dispatch table which uses hash codes to specify which sets of rules need actually be scanned for a particular input expression.

What is a hash table? How does it specify which sets of rules need actually be scanned for a particular input expression?

What about `DeleteCases`? Since it is fast too, Does it use hash table too?

Comment: I think this question is likely off-topic as it is about a common data structure.  See [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right, but I think this question could attract good answers about Mma internals. Let's see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, I admit it is a little off-topic. And I was wondering if `DeleteCases` also use hash table? Because it is fast too.

Comment: @rm-rf For the case where the r.h.s. of `DeleteCases` is an alternative pattern (`Alternatives[elems]`), and when `elems` do not contain patterns, since V8 `DeleteCases` has been optimized to work really fast, even for the large number of `elems`. I strongly suspect that a hash table was used internally in this case. And this may well be what the OP means here, since I do recall some comments by the OP related to this particular issue.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Wouldn't that then be an improvement to `Alternatives`? I thought `DeleteCases` by itself was just a tree traversal?

Comment: @rm-rf It would, in case if it was implemented consistently across all functions which work with `Alternatives`. Since this change has been made specifically for `DeleteCases`, it is de facto an improvement for `DeleteCases`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ah, ok then. I thought that it was quite random to pair up DeleteCases with hash tables, but what you say makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @rm-rf No problem :)

Comment: As @LeonidShifrin (and the original poster and maybe others) surmise, that special case of `DeleteCases` uses a hash table. `Cases` likewise.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I should have probably mentioned that this optimization was your contribution. Very useful thing.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Do you care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @belisarius Okay, done. For what little I could say about the main part of the question, I might as well have deferred to Shirley...

Answer (score 4):

As @LeonidShifrin (and the original poster and maybe others) surmise, that special case of DeleteCases uses a hash table. Cases likewise.

This does not really address the original question, to wit, how is hashing used behind the scenes with dispatch tables. In truth I do not know the answer to that. I will surmise that subexpressions are hashed and only dispatch table rules with left-hand-sides of same hash value are applied. But that's just a wild guess.